# How to use thread on just one line of python, not for all the script

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.5

I need to know if there is a way I can just use multithreading in a single line, rather than the full program.

That is, I want to run the program as a single thread, but in the middle of it I want one particular line to be multithreaded. I want to multithread something like this:

```
br.open("http://www.google.com.pk/search?q="+str(m))
```

So, basically I want to open all the links (`m` can assume 50 distinct values), and I don't want to open them one after the other. I want to open all 50 at once! If I open them one by one, it slows the process down and I want to avoid that.

Comment: Just as a general comment, unrelated to _how_ to do this: Each of those `open` calls sends an HTTP request, and you should be careful about how many requests you send to the server (especially, Google) at once. They may block you if you do a lot of this without proper breaks / sleeps in between.

Comment: Also, opening 50 threads at once doesn't necessarily make things faster. Anyway, here's some inspiration: [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/)

Comment: Are you running the new 25-core hyperthreading CPU?

Comment: @ jedwards I have Core i7 2600k - @ phg As for the threading it will open 50 links once not like sequence wise - and that sequence wise makes it slower because when I open it once it takes 2 -4 sec to load the page -

Answer (score 3):

You want to look at the [threading.Thread](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) class.

```
import threading

def worker():
    """thread worker function"""
    print 'Worker'
    return

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

If you are doing multiple HTTP requests you may also want to look at [queue.Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) You would then queue up multiple http requests. [Here](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/Queue/index.html) is a nice example of that in action.

Answer (score 1):

You are after asynchronous communications. I haven't tried it myself, but take a look at [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests). It used to be part of the requests library, but has been factored out. Usage (from their github page) seems very easy:

```
import grequests

urls = [
    'http://www.heroku.com',
    'http://tablib.org',
    'http://httpbin.org',
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]
rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
grequests.map(rs)
```

If you want to keep within the Python standard library, you might take a look at the [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html#module-asyncore) module.

Also, another alternative is [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com). It might be overkill for your requirements, and the learning curve is notoriously steep.

Answer (score 0):

I would here be actually trying to answer the original question asked by the OP, I don't recommend this code due to obvious readability issues but just like in Java you can actually run a thread from a single line in Python.

We will be using the Thread Class from Python

```
from threading import Thread
```

Define the Function which you want to call.

```
def func1():
   print("Hello World")
```

Start a thread from one single line

```
Thread(target=func1).start()
```

That is how you start one liner thread in python. 
For [information on how to pass arguments to target function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913201/pass-keyword-arguments-to-target-function-in-python-threading-thread)