# Pass keyword arguments to target function in Python threading.Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading, keyword-argument

I want to pass named arguments to the target function, while creating a Thread object.

Following is the code that I have written:

```
import threading

def f(x=None, y=None):
    print x,y

t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(x=1,y=2,))
t.start()
```

I get a syntax error for "x=1", in Line 6.
I want to know how I can pass keyword arguments to the target function.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)?

Comment: You don't need to use specify the names of the arguments, you can use a plain tuple: `t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(1,2,))`

Answer (score 139, accepted):

```
t = threading.Thread(target=f, kwargs={'x': 1,'y': 2})
```

this will pass a dictionary with the keyword arguments' names as keys and argument values as values in the dictionary.
the other answer above won't work, because the "x" and "y" are undefined in that scope.

another example, this time with multiprocessing, passing both positional and keyword arguments:

the function used being:

```
def f(x, y, kw1=10, kw2='1'):
    pass
```

and then when called using multiprocessing:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('a1', 2,), kwargs={'kw1': 1, 'kw2': '2'})
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: I have no problem with vladosaurus's answer as it is. Longer isn't always more helpful; being concise is. In this case it saves my day within seconds.

Answer (score 16):

You can also just pass a dictionary straight up to kwargs:

```
import threading

def f(x=None, y=None):
    print x,y

my_dict = {'x':1, 'y':2}
t = threading.Thread(target=f, kwargs=my_dict)
t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `args` with `kwargs={x: 1, y: 2}`.

Comment: Surely not. ITYM `{'x': 1, 'y': 2}`, which is a huge difference.