# How to multiprocessing Api post request

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I successfully post each record one by one from a csv file. However, I'm trying to implement multiprocessing to make it more efficient to handle large data file in the future.

```
ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://example.com'
headers = {'Api-key': '123abc'}

with open("student.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r ]
    groups = {}

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['name'])):
        #My data mapping

        #for loop to post each record
        post_api = requests.post(ENDPOINT_URL, json=groups, headers=headers)
```

Is there any new easy way to do the multiprocessing for api request?

Update: I trying to use the `grequest` but the data i post is null

```
rs = (grequests.post(u,json=groups, headers=headers) for u in ENDPOINT_URL)
    grequests.map(rs)

    print(grequests.map(rs))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `threading` library.

```
ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://example.com'
headers = {'Api-key': '123abc'}

import threading
with open("student.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r ]
    groups = {}

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['name'])):
        #My data mapping
        t = threading.Thread(target=requests.post,
                             args=(ENDPOINT_URL, groups, headers=headers))
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()
```

Notice: `setDaemon(True)` will make the thread automatically kill itself after finishing the job.

Update: if you want to pass keyword arguments check here: [keyword arguments threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913201/pass-keyword-arguments-to-target-function-in-python-threading-thread)

Comment: May I know why have to add `args=`?Because it is a syntax error at `json=grops`.

Comment: I removed the  `args` but got this `TypeError: 'Response' object is not callable`

Comment: I updated my answer, `args` takes the parameter tuple needed by your function. in this case `requests.post`, if you want to provide keyword such as `json=groups` do it via `kwargs`

Comment: May I know how could I print the output? It doesn't support like `print(t.text)`. It is unclear if I `print(t)`